# Problems running rake with rspec and ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I am trying to run rake on a ruby file where I am supposed to receive an error so I can debug it as an exercise. However the error I get is not the error Im supposed to receive. I'm receiving the following and I'm having a time interpreting what I need to fix.

```
~Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello$ rake
(in /~Desktop/learn_ruby-master)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file --     hello (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from ~Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb:117:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in     `block in autorun'
```

rake aborted!

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -S rspec ~Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -    I/~Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello -I/~Desktop/learn_ruby-master/00_hello/solution -f     documentation -r ./rspec_config failed

Tasks: TOP => default => spec
(    See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the code I am running rake on

```
    require "hello"

describe "the hello function" do
  it "says hello" do
    hello.should == "Hello!"
  end
end

describe "the greet function" do
  it "says hello to someone" do
    greet("Alice").should == "Hello, Alice!"
  end

  it "says hello to someone else" do
    greet("Bob").should == "Hello, Bob!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby says it all: "Cannot find filename hello.rb on the library loading path". You are missing hello.rb file or Ruby cannot find it. Do you really have it on the disc in the directory you run rake from? If its somewhere else you need to provide relative path.

Also remove the whitespace from the first line, I suspect you have some gargabe there. There should be only one space between -- and hello in the error message.

Comment: lzap, Thanks. The error you mention is what I am supposed to be working on and I went through the steps as it mentioned in exercise but the error message is different than the one quoted. Moreover when I create the hello.rb file that Ruby wants (within the same directory) the error message does not change. Additionally even when I remove the 'require "Hello"' statement I continue to receive this error message. If it is exactly what you say it is then how would I point rake to its path since it doesnt seem to be finding hello.rb within the same directory? Thanks again.

Comment: Ruby 1.8 does try to find in the current directory, Ruby 1.9+ does not. Try to add require "./hello" there.

Comment: when I did it exactly as you say the error message remains unchanged. When I add the ./ in front of the string I get: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:34:in `require': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)  <br/>
And then I get the exact same error message as above starting with  <br/>     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'

Comment: It must be in the string, like that: require "./xyz"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (going through the exact same tutorial).  I just spent three days of my life trying to figure it out.  The issue was that one of my folders in the path to 'hello.rb' had a space in between two words.  Seriously, that was it.  The ruby path couldn't pick it up no matter what I did (except change the space).  Uggh.  Lesson learned, don't name anything, anywhere with a space from here on out.